# Wait the car cool down first

Tags: grammar

The wheater was hot.

We back to car after shopping.

I started the car and asked my son stand under the roof.

"**Wait the car cool down first.**"

Does it sound natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Wait the car cool down first."

Is not correct.

Please try: "Wait for the car to cool down first". The addition of "for" sets the condition. It is correct to use "for" [when it is followed by a direct object.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/wait-or-wait-for) Additionally we need to add "to" before the word "cool" resulting in "to cool". [Here is a link](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-use-preposition-to-1211798) with some helpful information about the ways "to" can be used.